# how to find all the cards of a suit specified by String e.g. "Spades" in java

Tags: java, arraylist, playing-cards

I'm trying to find all the cards of same suit and return it.  I've tried everything but I don't seem to get it right.

```
public ArrayList<Card> findSuit(String suit) {

 ArrayList<Card> cards = new ArrayList<Card>();
  for(int i = 1; i <= pack.size(); i++){
   cards.add(i);
  }         
      return cards;   
 }
```

The error message that I'm getting is:

> The method add(int, Card) in the type ArrayList is not applicable for the arguments (int)

Comment: This looks a lot like homework.

Comment: You're being sarcastic, right? :)

Comment: This looks a lot like sarcasm.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that

- `pack` is defined as a `List<Card>` or `ArrayList<Card>`
- `pack` is visible inside the function
- the `Card` class has a method named `getSuit()` returning the suit as a String

then the following will work.

```
public List<Card> findSuit(String suit) {

  List<Card> cards = new ArrayList<Card>();
  for ( Card card : pack ) {
    if ( card.getSuit().equals(suit) )  {
      cards.add(card); 
    }
  }

  return cards;
 }
```

Changed == to `equals` (i usually use enums for this kind of thing).

Comment: == ? you need to use equals()

Answer (score 2):

First of all, indexes in collections start from 0 and ends in size()-1.

I assume that the class Card has a property suit. So the code:

```
for(Card c : pack) {
    if(c != null && c.getSuit().equals(suit)){
        cards.add(c);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to `add()` a reference to an object of the proper class, `Card` in this case. It's hard to know how to create such an object without seeing the class definition, but perhaps `cards.add(new Card(i))` works, if there is a constructor from an integer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a card object (e.g. of class `Card`) to an arraylist, which is specified by a [second argument to `add()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add%28int,%20java.lang.Object%29)

E.g. if you have

```
Card my_card;
```

Then you do:

```
cards.add(i, my_card);
```

Of course, you need to actually create the `Card` object via Card class constructor so they can be added.

Comment: I suppose you mean `cards.add(i, my_card);`

Answer (score 0):

.Add takes an index (int) and an element (of type Object).
You are only specifying int.

See the documents for a description and examples:
http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add(int, java.lang.Object)